# How to manipulate the iframe css based on device size

Tags: html, css

I'm building this site and I'm having trouble manipulating the iframe based on size of the device. Basically, what I want is if the use is on a tablet the video is one size but for example if the user is on a mobile device like a cell phone it is other size recommended it be smaller that the tablet or desktop window size. if any of that makes since.

I've tried using div's but I may have implemented then wrong but from all I researched I doubt it. I also made an iframe in the CSS just for that device size and had a default iframe for all devices.

```css
@media only screen and (max-device-width:480px){
   /* styles for mobile browsers smaller than 480px; (iPhone) */
    .center{   
      width: 300px;
      height: 100px;
      position: fixed;
      left: 48.5%;
      top: 44%;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);     
    }
 iframe {
  border:none;
  overflow:hidden; 
  width: 500px; 
  height: 250px;
  frameborder="0";
  allowTransparency="true"; 
  allowFullScreen="true";
 }
}
iframe {
  border:none;
  overflow:hidden; 
  width: 1000px; 
  height: 500px;
  frameborder="0";
  allowTransparency="true"; 
  allowFullScreen="true";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <p align="center">
  <!--stackoverflow trying to get the videos to shrink when using mobile devices. need to be done for "ipad" and cell phones from my knowledge computers are fine. --> 
  <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fwhereisslice%2Fvideos%2F1034464440067039%2F&show_text=0&width=560">
  </iframe>
  
  </p>
  <p align="center">
  
  <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FTimeOutForMeInc%2Fvideos%2F526931557744638%2F&show_text=0&width=267" >
  </iframe>
  
  </p>   
 </body>
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.embed-container {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 0;
   padding-bottom: 56.27198%;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center center;
 }

.embed-container iframe {
 position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%
 }
```

```html
<div class='embed-container'><iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fwhereisslice%2Fvideos%2F1034464440067039%2F&show_text=0&width=560"></iframe></div>
```

[more detail](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/)

Comment: can I get you to example a little about this?

Comment: one question why is there one video over top each other? I'm having trouble separating them.